# Graph analysis of accelerometer data

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, acceleration, data-analysis, sensor

I used my mobile accelerometer sensor to collect data from a moving bike where I held it in my hand in a way that the smartphone sensor +Y axis is in the direction of the moving bike always.
This can be shown as below:
[image]

Now, I followed a simple path as shown below
[image]

The graph I obtained is shown below in x and y axis.
[image]
[image]

Now i have interpreted that the time 14.958 to 21 and 21 to 25.5 in x acceleration graph is for turn 1 and 2 respectively. Now in the y graph the time 21.912 to 34.298 is for braking.

What I want to know is that are my interpretations correct . Also I think that as the Y axis is in the direction of travel, the X acceleration directly gives me the radial acceleration. Also I cant quite make out why there is a rise in the graph after braking(time 34.298 onwards).

Please also explain if the values are in acceptable range.

The acceleration in the z direction is shown below. The sharp peaks may be due the pitching of the bike while braking.
[image]

I have even added the one with all 3, but I don't think it will be of much help,since all the lines are messed together.
[image]

PS: The acceleration is in m/s^2 and the time in seconds.

Comment: This may be due to an unsteady hand. It is probably not meaningful to guess what this is due to without z-axis data.

Comment: I have added the z accleration .

Comment: Can it be more clear if my interpretations are correct now? And are the values within the acceptable limits?

Comment: One would like to have a movie to see durations of the different turns. That could also give an estimate of the accelerations. And you should probably smooth the data. But even if your hand was perfectly steady, a cyclist leans over to the other side to initiate a curve. Difficult.

Comment: Yeah sure, actually in real life scenario , the vibrations of the vehicle, the sway of our body and other noises come into account which is why obtaining a graph as clean as physics class rooms is difficult . Anyways I had a talk regarding the data and for now I guess I can get the maximum acceleration experienced by the vehicle .

Comment: Maybe around turns of a defined radius , mv^2/r will work better.